# Passing parameters to the Stanford NER in C#

Tags: c#, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am loading the Stanford NER module in my C# code list this:

```
var classifier = CRFClassifier.getClassifierNoExceptions(@"..\..\NER\english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz");
```

I can see from the documentation (https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/memory-time.html) that there are a number of parameters that would be useful in optimising my processing of text.

For example:

```
edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz -ner.useSUTime false -ner.applyNumericClassifiers false
```

Can anyone advise how I can pass these parameters into my classifier in c# please?